# What is the property where f(g(x)) = g(f(x))?

Tags: functions, terminology

What is the property where f(g(x)) = g(f(x))?

Comment: Here is a related post I made a while back: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have slipped up with the rollbacks here; on the other hand, it doesn't seem right that the "associative" part in the previous iteration of the question is missing...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Besides being called (composition) commutative, it is sometimes also said that such functions are *permutable*, e.g. see [here](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ritt+permutable). As an example, a [classic result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition/11442#11442) of Ritt shows that permutable polynomials are, up to a linear homeomorphism, either both powers of x, both iterates of the same polynomial, or both Chebychev polynomials.

Answer (score 15):

We say $f$ and $g$ commute (with respect to composition). The property is called "commutativity".

"Associativity" is the property that says that $f\circ (g\circ h)$ is the same as $(f\circ g)\circ h$, where $\circ$ is composition.