# When actually $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ holds?

Tags: functions, special-functions

We can see that if $f(x)=g(x)=x$ then $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$.
I would like to see other examples of functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$.

P.S. By definition we also must have $D_{f\circ g}= D_{g\circ f}$

Comment: @Workaholic the first and the third are clearly wrong  read the P.S.

Comment: something is wrong, all functions such that f=g satisfy the equation.

Comment: @runaround Why does that mean something is wrong? It just means you've found a family of solutions.

Comment: Relevant: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194115/when-does-function-composition-commute), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition)

Comment: @OmarNagib this is  wrong

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas what do you mean wrong?

Comment: Check the domain of the composition

Comment: If you've got a one-to-one(Injective) function $f(x)$, then you can always define its inverse $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$. for example, consider $f=x^3$ and $g=\sqrt [3] {x}$.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas both $f(g)$ and $g(f)$ maps from the reals to the reals. I cannot discern the problem.

Comment: From reals to reals?I am not sure check it again.

Comment: Note that two of the examples given so far fall into a general framework. Let $f: D \to D$ be a function, and consider composing $f$ with itself several times, possibly a negative number of times if $f$ is invertible. The generator function has been $f(x) = x + 1$ in both cases. Does the tag [tag:special-functions] imply that you really want special functions (like Bessel or Lambert W) to show up, or are you just considering functions that commute "special"?

Answer (score 7):

Functions need not be inverses of each other to commute. A simple example. Let $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x+2$.  Here, of course
$$f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x+3.$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a family of examples: let $h$ be any function from a set to itself, and $n,m$ any positive integers. Then $f(x)=h^m(x),g(x)=h^n(x)$ (here superscripts denote functional power, so for example $h^3(x)=h(h(h(x)))$). Then clearly $f(g(x))=h^{m+n}(x)=g(f(x))$.

Comment: If you generalise to $f^{-m} (x)=(f^{-1})^m (x)$, I think this encompasses all of the answers given so far. So the next natural question to ask is, "are these all the solutions?"

Comment: @bilaterus Certainly not. If you take $f(x)=x^\alpha,g(x)=x^\beta$ for some linearly independent $\alpha,\beta$, then I'd risk betting that $f,g$ aren't expressible as powers of fixed power $h$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x-1$

$$f(g(x))=g(x)+1\\
=(x-1)+1\\
=x\\
\text{ and }\\
g(f(x))=f(x)-1\\
(x+1)-1\\
=x$$

Comment: $x^2$ and $\sqrt x$ are wrong

Comment: You are not restricted to inverses:  $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x+2$ also work

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $\mathbf{R}_{\geqslant0}$ to $\mathbf{R}_{\geqslant0}$, where $f:x\mapsto x^2$ and $g:x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$, then $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$, and your desired condition $\operatorname{dom}(f\circ g)=\operatorname{dom}(g\circ f)$ still holds.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you take two inverse functions, defined over e.g. $\Bbb R$ (or over the same subset of $\Bbb R$),
then you trivially get the desired property, because $x = f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$.

Here is an example where the two functions are not inverse.

$f(x) = x^n$

$g(x) = x^m$

where $n$ and $m$ are e.g. integers

Also:

$f(x) = a \cdot x$

$g(x) = b \cdot x$

where $a$ and $b$ are e.g. reals

Comment: You got your answer in as I was typing. :)

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Sorry... I am not a fast typing person actually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's much to say.

There's $g= f^{-1}$ so $f (g (x)) = x $

Then there's $f = g $ so $f (g (x))e f (f (x)) $

Then there's $f (g (x)) = g (f (x)) = h (x)$ so $g (x) = f^{-1}(g(f (x))) = f^{-1}(h (x)) $ and/or $f (x)=g^{-1}(h (x))$.

As long as we can find invertible functions we can find these.  Is there anything more that needs to be said?

Comment: Eep!  Never mind.  The last part doesn't work!  (Obviously...)