# Is is true that: $f \circ g = g \circ f \implies$ $f$ is linear or $g$ is linear?

Tags: linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

Is the following statement true? In case not, what's a counterexample? Thank you.

> If $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are two continuous functions satisfying $f \circ g = g \circ f$, then either $f$ is linear or $g$ is linear (Where neither $f$ nor $g$ is invertible and $f \neq g$).

**Def:** $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be linear if, there exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: But $f$ linear $\Rightarrow f$ invertible so either way, no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A contradiction can be easily obtained by letting $f=g$ without $f$ being linear.

As an alternative example $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$

Comment: Or $f(x)=\ln\ln x$ and $g(x)=\ln\ln\ln x$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, though that's not what I was looking for. I'll ask another one.

Comment: @BolzWeir what are you looking for?

Comment: I should have worded my question more properly. I am looking for general sufficient conditions for that equality to hold. I am interested in a non-trivial condition.

Comment: I.e., a condition which does not look like $f = g^n$, etc. Something that is analytical in flavor.

Comment: This appears to be related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition

Comment: I had not thought about these cases and that's why I put the condition as: $f$ is linear, thinking that this would prevent the attempts to answer the question at face value. The link you gave is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Look at what happens if $f=g$. Or $f=g^2$ - or, in general $f=h^a$ and $g=h^b$ for some function $h$. We only need to use the associativity of composition to prove that these commute.

Answer (score 0):

Two sets of functions
such that
$h_n(h_m(x))
=h_{mn}(x)
$
are the powers
($h_n(x)
=x^n
$)
and the
Chebychev polynomials
(look them up)
$h_n(x)
=T_n(x)
$.

For distinct
$m$ and $n$
set
$f(x) = h_n(x)$
and
$g(x) = h_m(x)$.

Then
$f(g(x))
=h_n(h_m(x))
=h_{nm}(x)
=h_{mn}(x)
=h_m(h_n(x))
=g(f(x))
$.

Comment: Indeed, I believe that there’s a theorem of Ritt that says that these are essentially the only examples of *polynomials* with the property $f\circ g=g\circ f$ other than pairs that are iterates of some polynomial.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Nice when I can be exhaustive rather than exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

In general, let

> $$
> f(x) = h^{[m]}(x) \quad \textrm{and} \quad g(x) = h^{[n]} h(x),
> $$

where

> $$
> h^{[n+1]}(x) = h \circ h^{[n]}(x),
> $$

then

> $$
> f \circ g(x) = g \circ f(x),
> $$

and $f(x)$ nor $g(x)$ is linear.