# How can I approach this question in other way without proving that $p(x)=x$ is a unique solution? $p(x^2+1)=(p(x))^2 +1$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> If $p(x)$ is polynomial such that $$p(x^2+1)=(p(x))^2 +1$$ and $p(0)=0$ then $p'(0)$ is equal to _____.

**Attempt**

While looking on it and putting $x=0$ I got $p(1)=1$ and also the equation given had also the similar form (in comparison) of $$y^2+1=(y^2)+1$$. So, I put this polynomial in test and found that it satisfies this as 
$p(x^2+1)=x^2+1$ and and $p(x)=x$ and hence it satisfied for every real x and so $p'(0)=1$. But I was not able to progress in the direction of correct solving.

Also, the given related problem is there on this site but, **I have not been taught the coefficient determination and hence that answer there is out of my scope for now**. But,I think there is this derivative method which I am currently learning and can understand about it.**So, I would like to know how to approach this in derivative method and also if there is any other easier way without proving $p(x)$ to be the unique solution.**

**Also, it may happen that if any other exists,then many persons will get to know about the new method. It will be more helpful to them and me inlcuded.**

So, is there any hints or suggestions on this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Apparently $p(x)=x$ is a solution, and then $p'(0)=1$. The phrasing of the question implies that $p'(0)$ is uniquely determined by the given functional equation, and so $p'(0)=1$ is the answer.

Comment: @daw Then it will be $p'(x^2+1)2x=2p(x)p'(x)$

Comment: @daw It's not immediately obvious how that helps, as inserting $x = 0$ into that relation just tells us that $0 =0$. So why don't you flesh it out a bit and make an actual answer out of it?

Comment: Related: [Determine all real polynomials with $P(0)=0$ and $P(x^2+1)=(P(x))^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897673/determine-all-real-polynomials-with-p0-0-and-px21-px21)

Comment: @Servaes: Related (and perhaps useful), but not necessarily a duplicate. There might be an easier proof of $p`(0)=1$, without showing first that $p(x)=x$ is the only solution.

Comment: Taking derivatives of the functional equation only leads to $p'(1) = p'(0)^2$, which also follows by comparing coefficients.

Comment: @daw can you please elaborate? I am only getting 0=0 after derivative taking and putting x=0.

Comment: you can divide the derivative equation by $2x$ then pass to the limit $x\to0$.

Comment: Please review it, I have asked for methods other than proving that $p(x) =x$ will be the only solution for above problem.

Comment: @daw: I don't yet see how that works out. But the question has been reopened, so you can add an answer if you like!

Answer (score 1):

The value of $p'(0)$ cannot determined uniquely unless we utilize the information that $p$ is polynomial critically at some point. Indeed,

> **Claim.** For any $c \in [0, \infty)$, there exists a smooth function $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> $$p(x^2 + 1) = p(x)^2 + 1, \qquad p(0) = 0, \qquad p'(0) = c. $$

Because the proof is rather technical and I do not want to digress, let me skip the full proof. But the idea is that, starting with any function $p_0 : [0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ with $p_0(0) = 0$, we can define $p$ on $[0, \infty)$ by

$$ p(x) = \big(f^{\circ n} \circ p_0 \circ f^{\circ(-n)} \big)(x), \qquad \text{if} \quad x \in \big[ f^{\circ n}(0), f^{\circ(n+1)}(0) \big)$$

and then extend to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by the relation $p(-x) = -p(x)$.

That said, one must take advantage of the fact that $p$ is polynomial. But since the derivative method does not distinguish polynomials from other smooth functions, I see no easy way of utilizing this method to solve OP's problem other than showing $p(x) = x$ first.

In this regard, let me introduce a solution which relies on the following simple fact:

> **Lemma.** If $q$ is a polynomial which has infinitely many zeros, then $q(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Now define $x_0 = 0$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 1$. Then we can inductively prove that $p(x_n) = x_n$. Indeed, this is true for $n = 0$ by the assumption. Moreover, if $p(x_n) = x_n$ is true for $n$, then

$$ p(x_{n+1}) = p(x_n^2 + 1) = p(x_n)^2 + 1 = x_n^2 + 1 = x_{n+1}. $$

Then applying Lemma to the polynomial $p(x) - x$, which has infinitely many zeros $x_0, x_1, \cdots$, we conclude that $p(x) = x$ and hence $p'(0) = 1$. $\square$.

Comment: Nice.... shows that it's unlikely there is an elementary solution that avoids showing $p(x)=x$, but more importantly, shows that proving $p(x)=x$ is itself simple and short and only needs knowing that a (non-$0$) real polynomial has only finitely many roots (no calculus nor coefficient calculations are needed)

Comment: @Ned, That's how I believe so. Indeed, the derivative method is not quite suited for distinguishing polynomials from other smooth functions, so I can hardly think of any easy solution in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the link proposed as a duplicate solves this.

**a more advanced perspective**
There are very limited possibilities where two polynomials commute under composition (in characteristic zero).

Note that $S(x):=x^2+1$ is not conjugate to the degree $2$ Chebyshev polynomial.  Therefore, the only polynomials that commute with $S$ under composition are the compositional powers $S^{[n]}$, $n=0,1,2,\cdots$.  The only compositional power $p$ with $S^{[n]}(0)=0$ is $S^{[0]}$ (the constant terms increase with $n$).  So $p(x) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $p$ satisfies the equation
$$
p'(x^2+1)\cdot 2x = 2p(x)p'(x).
$$
Dividing by $2x$, and passing to the limit $x\to 0$ we get 
$$
p'(1) = p'(0)^2,
$$
because $p(x)/x \to p'(0)$ for $x\to0$.

I do not see how to obtain $p'(0)$ without proving $p(x)=x$.
The relation $p'(1) = p'(0)^2$ can also be obtained by comparing the polynomial coefficients in the original function equation.