# Abelian monoids and integer polynomial composition?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, commutative-algebra, function-and-relation-composition, monoid

Consider distinct integer polynomials of distinct degree. Also they are all univariate polynomials of the variable $x$.

Let $*$ denote composition and $*$ is the operation for the monoid.
Consider when such polynomials $a,b,c,d$ forms an abelian monoid.

Many questions arise naturally.
For instance

1) can we classify them ?

2) Is every finitely generated abelian monoid a submonoid of a nonfinitely generated abelian monoid ?

3) if the distinct integer polynomials $x,y$ satisfy

$$ x * y = y * x $$

Does that imply they belong to an abelian monoid with polynomials of degree other than $1$ and No common divisors with $deg(y)$ or $deg(x)$ ?

4) If an Abelian monoid is not finitely generated and is not an abelian submonoid , does that imply that the degrees of the polynomials are dense in the positieve integers ?

5) If the Abelian monoid is not finitely generated does that imply that there exists an analytic function $F $ and the functional inverse ( of $F$) $G $ such that all elements are given by

$$ F( n \space G(x) ) $$

For some integer $n$ ,where $n$ is the degree ? ( I did not say Every integer $n $ is a Solution ! )

6) I only know solutions

$$exp( n \space ln(x)), sin( n \space arcsin(x)) , cos( n \space arccos(x) ) $$

as Abelian monoids.
What are the others ?? [ MAIN QUESTION ! ]

Comment: See chebyshev polynomials If you are confused.

Comment: Abelian monoid = commutative monoid.

Comment: The search term to look for is "commuting polynomials".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition

Comment: Please address your 6 questions in separate posts and note that your main question is a duplicate, as Hurkyl pointed out.