# What functions satisfy $f \circ g = g \circ f\ne \text{id}$?

Tags: functional-equations

> What functions satisfy $f \circ g = g \circ f\ne \text{id}$ and $f \ne g$?

**Some thoughts:**
This is fulfilled for $f(x) := \alpha x$ and $g(x) := \beta x$ for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha \beta \ne 1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ because of commutativity of real numbers, but are there other not so trivial examples and how can they be characterised?

**Edit to reflect how this shouldn't be a duplicate.**
The *accepted* answer on the suggested duplicate is very interesting and informative but only deals with polynomials / rational functions and there are a lot of other functions that could fit this description (and if not, why?).

Comment: You probably want $f \neq \text{id}$ and $g \neq \text{id}$ too.

Comment: Let  $p$ be a point in the plane and $f$ and $g$ be any rotations around $p$. (Although this  can be understood as a generalizion of your example, with $f(z)=p+(z-p)a$ and $g(z) = p+(z-p)b$.)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is related to at least two others, $x+\alpha$ vs $x+\beta$ with $\alpha+\beta\ne0$ and $x^\alpha$ vs $x^\beta$ (where I'll leave you to work out suitable constraints on $\alpha,\,\beta$, bearing in mind what happens if $x<0$).

Answer (score 1):

> A [classic result of
>   Ritt](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1923-025-03/S0002-9947-1923-1501252-3/S0002-9947-1923-1501252-3.pdf)
>   shows that polynomials that commute under composition must be, up to a
>   linear homeomorphism, either both powers of $x$, both iterates of the
>   same polynomial, or both  Chebychev polynomials. Actually Ritt proved
>   a more general rational function case - follow the link. His work was
>   motivated by work of Julia and Fatou's work on Julia sets of rational
>   functions, e.g. see
>   [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.8482)
>   for a modern presentation.

A answer by [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) on [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition).