# Is there a name for when $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$

Tags: functions

This question came about when I was using LaTeX, funny enough. I noticed that the following equivalence in syntax when typing the Hamiltonian operator:

```
\hat{mathcal{H}}
\mathcal{\hat{H}}
```

Both yield the same resulting character, $\mathcal{\hat{H}}$.

Noticing that these two "functions," `\hat` and `\mathcal`, are interchangeable, I couldn't help but notice a similarity with math.

Is there anything in mathematics in which two functions are interchangeable in this manner?

Comment: I guess you could those functions 'commuting'. There are many cases in which commuting functions play a special role

Comment: Commuting fits with the existing idea of commuting operators and matrices. There is also a related language of “intertwining”.

Comment: [Very related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558831/is-there-an-interesting-graphical-intuition-about-what-the-condition-f-circ-g#comment9589800_4558831).